# Name for special product of sets

Tags: terminology

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. What is this type of product called: $AB = \{ xy \;:\; x \in A,\; y \in B \}$?

I found this notation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum in Section 4.1.

Comment: Point-wise / element-wise product?

Comment: In group theory it's called the *complex product". In geometry the additive analogue $A+B=\{x+y:x\in A,y\in B\}$ is called the "Minkowski sum".

Comment: @bof I can't find any online reference that calls this product a "complex product"...

Comment: See page 6 of [this text](http://www.math.ku.dk/~olsson/manus/GruFus/Kurzweil-Stellmacher_Theory%20of%20finite%20groups.pdf).